# invalid list of arguments when including numerical recipes nr3.h on c++ builder

Tags: c++, c++builder, c++builder-xe2

I tried to use [numerical recipes version 3](http://www.nr.com/codefile.php?nr3) within my c++ project using c++ Builder from RAD XE 2.
However, the compiler complains about all lines like

```
typedef const NRvector<Int> VecInt_I;
typedef NRvector<Int> VecInt, VecInt_O, VecInt_IO;
```

... saying "ungültige Argumentenliste" (sorry for German), which translates to `invalid list of arguments`.

Using the same file in a simple empty program works fine, though...

But if I write at the beginning of my c++ project

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop    
#include "nr3.h"

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

... it gives me this error.

Is there a compiler-option that is causing this? Maybe some C++ Builder project setting?

Comment: What is `Int`? And can you please show a more complete example code that exhibits your problem (a so called [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), including marking the *exact* line(s) where the error is. Also, please include the *complete* and *unedited* error log.

Comment: To be slightly more direct about what @JoachimPileborg said, the keyword in `C++` is `int`, not `Int`, unless you `typedef`'d that too.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg the minimal example would be an `int main(){return 0;}` that has the libaries I mentioned above. Int as well as Doub and a lot of other types get typedef'd by numerical recipes, too. my current guess is, that nr3.h isn't working well with the vcl.h libary.

Comment: @Julian are you saying that the 7 lines of code you show starting from `#include <vcl.h>` , on its own, gives those compilation errors?

Comment: @MattMcNabb yep^^ Thanks for your answer below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nr3.h` does `using namespace std;` and it also pollutes the global namespace with all of its typedefs. The problem with the line:

```
typedef const NRvector<Int> VecInt_I;
```

and the other lines involving `Int` is because `Int` is resolved to `System::Int` (`vcl.h` includes this function's definition and also `using namespace System;`) .

There are further errors with

```
typedef const NRmatrix<Char> MatChar_I;
```

because of ambiguity between `System::Char` (a type) and `Char` defined by `nr3.h`.

---

There's no simple fix. `nr3.h` has multiple serious issues, not just that it pollutes the global namespace. As a band-aid you could edit it so that it puts all of its definitions in a namespace (say `NR3`) , and take out `using namespace std;` . But even if you get it compiling, this code is so dreadful that you will run into many other issues later on. My advice would be to simply not use it, and either write your own code based on its algorithms or look for some other solution entirely.

Comment: +1. That would be my exact advice. Never use NR code directly; instead use it as a guide to the algorithm and your own, probably better, implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... It's a shame it got so many issues despite having such a professional feeling to it... I used a nr2-code now instead and rewrote it slightly. It surely has more a c-feeling to it than a c++, but it's easier to rewrite and understand in my opinion.